# I am using ffmpeg to overlay a image on top of a live stream using filter graphs, but when the input resolution changes, the overlay vanishes

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, http-live-streaming

I did my research and found that some filter graph options do not adapt to changing resolutions.
https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/libav-user/2012-October/002920.html
Here is the command which i am using. Whenever my input video changes from portrait to landscape, the overlay vanishes. I would really appreciate any help here.

```
ffmpeg  -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/show/$2 -i $overlayUrl  -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref=iw:ih[ovr][base];[base][ovr] overlay=0:0, split=4[a][b]" -async 1 -vsync -1 -map 0:a -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 256k -b:a 32k -s 640x360 -tune zerolatency -r 60 -preset  veryfast -crf 23 -f flv rtmp://$rtmpoutput/$2_low -map 0:a -map "[b]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:v 768k -b:a 96k -s 640x480 -tune zerolatency -r 60 -preset veryfast -crf 23 -f flv rtmp://$rtmpoutput/$2_mid code here
```

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg reinitializes the filtergraph when input properties change. The image input is one frame long and has already been consumed.

Loop the image.

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/show/$2 -loop 1 -i $overlayUrl ...
```